# Select two files in the if exist command

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, file-exists

The truth is I'm new to programming. So I'd be happy if you could help me.
I need to select two things in the "if exits" command, that is, either the two files or one of them, to which the following command applies.
This is the code:

```
if exist *.mp3 *.wma *.wav goto music
if exist *.mp4 *.mov goto video
if exist *.docx *.txt *.pdf goto document
if exist *.jpg *.png goto image
goto end
:music
md Music
move *.mp3 Music
move *.wma Music
move *.wav Music
if exist *.mp4 *.mov goto video
if exist *.docx *.txt *.pdf goto document
if exist *.jpg *.png goto image
goto end
:video
md Video
move *.mp4 Video
move *.mov Video
if exist *.docx *.txt *.pdf goto document
if exist *.jpg *.png goto image
goto end
:document
md Documents
move *.docx Documents
move *.txt Documents
move *.pdf Documents
if exist *.jpg *.png goto image
goto end
:image
md Pictures
move *.jpg Pictures
move *.png Pictures
goto end
:end
exit
```

I searched and did not find, tried all kinds of options and did not succeed.
Thank you!

Comment: If exist is not the command you want here. Open CMD, type `For /?`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace your whole code with just the following four lines:

```
for %%a in (mp3 wma wav) do if exist *.%%a md music 2>nul & move *.%%a music\
for %%a in (mp4 mov) do if exist *.%%a md video 2>nul & move *.%%a video\
for %%a in (docx txt pdf) do if exist *.%%a md documents 2>nul & move *.%%a documents\
for %%a in (jpg png) do if exist *.%%a md pictures 2>nul & move *.%%a pictures\
```

Comment: Amazing! you are awesome!!!
I just didn't understand what is command 2>nul
Thank you!

Comment: `2>nul` suppresses the errormessage when `md` tries to create a folder that is already present (it's easier this way than to check first if the folder already exists). `2` is the "error stream". See [here](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a loop to iterate the values:

```
for %%a in (mp3 wma wav) do if exist *.%%a goto music
```

To make things more readable you can even define a macros and reuse them:

```
::::: marco ::::::::::
set "if_one_of=for %%a in ("
set "exist=) do if exist *.%%a"
:::::::::::::::::::::::

%if_one_of% mp3 wma wav %exist% goto music
```

more about [FOR](https://ss64.com/nt/for2.html)

Comment: Thank you very much! You helped me a lot!